# windows store winjs app uploading giving error 2001

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, winjs, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to upload an app to windows store which was maintained and uploaded before by my colleague.

I cloned the project, cleaned the project and rebuilded it and updated package (.appxupload) to the Windows Store and it tells me "This submission failed with error code(s) 2001. More info about the error(s) can be found here." with a reference to this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/resolve-submission-errors

When we tried to build the same project in my colleagues system its getting uploaded with out any errors but when i try to upload the same code its giving me error

I can sucessfully build and deploy my app with Visual Studio in both release and debug mode, and also pass the certification, but the Store stops me

My colleauge is using Visual Studio Community 2013 and am using Visual Studio Community Edition 2015.Is this due to any system dependencies.Any ideas?